# How to edit out particular json attributes? Can regex on VSCode work?

Tags: json, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a json file with an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "db",
    "_type": "service",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 4.0,
    "_source": {
      "contentId": "1",
      "title": "Sample 1",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "keyword": ["sample1", "service"],
      "desp": "Desc this Service",
      "contentType": "service",
      "url": null,
      "contentCategory": "Services",
      "contentSubCategory": null,
      "assignmentProfile": null,
      "employeeId": null,
      "assignmentProfileId": null,
      "managedRuleId": null,
      "contentAcademy": null,
      "imageUrl": null,
      "metaData": [
        "sample1",
        "services"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "db",
    "_type": "service",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 7.0,
    "_source": {
      "contentId": "2",
      "title": "Sample 2",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "keyword": ["sample2", "service"],
      "desp": "Desc this Service",
      "contentType": "service",
      "url": null,
      "contentCategory": "Services",
      "contentSubCategory": null,
      "assignmentProfile": null,
      "employeeId": null,
      "assignmentProfileId": null,
      "managedRuleId": null,
      "contentAcademy": null,
      "imageUrl": null,
      "metaData": [
        "sample2",
        "services"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I need to remove certain fields in this. All the fields beginning with the `_` and `metadata` field. It needs to end up like this:

```
[
  {
    "contentId": "1",
    "title": "Sample 1",
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "keyword": ["sample1", "service"],
    "desp": "Desc this Service",
    "contentType": "service",
    "url": null,
    "contentCategory": "Services",
    "contentSubCategory": null,
    "assignmentProfile": null,
    "employeeId": null,
    "assignmentProfileId": null,
    "managedRuleId": null,
    "contentAcademy": null,
    "imageUrl": null
  },
  {
    "contentId": "2",
    "title": "Sample 2",
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "keyword": ["sample2", "service"],
    "desp": "Desc this Service",
    "contentType": "service",
    "url": null,
    "contentCategory": "Services",
    "contentSubCategory": null,
    "assignmentProfile": null,
    "employeeId": null,
    "assignmentProfileId": null,
    "managedRuleId": null,
    "contentAcademy": null,
    "imageUrl": null
  }
]
```

I want to write a regex expression on VSCode to do the above. I wrote the following:

```
"metaData": \[\r\n (.+) ],
```

to replace the metaData attribute with a empty string. But that doesn't match.

The array size is 100+ and thus is there a expression to match this with?

Comment: In VSCode, you do not need `\r\n`, just use `\r` or `\n`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still doesnt match. Is only able to match till `"metaData": \[`

Comment: You may use `^(?:\s*"_[^"]*":.*\n?)+` and then `,\s*"metaData":.*\n?\s*}`, replace with an empty string both times.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want it's value removed too along with one curly braces after it

Comment: Have you tried my two-step solution yet?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the first exp. works perfectly. second doesn't though. Can you link any resources which explains the different symbols? I'd like to learn but most Ive seen are quite difficult to understand

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry. I had the wrong format for "metadata" here. updated now to actual data

Comment: Ok, so the second must be `,(\n)\s*"metaData":[\s\S\n]*?\n\s*}\s*\n` => `$1`

Comment: still wont match. This: `,(\n)\s*"metaData":[\s\S\n]*?\n\s*` matches till before the first braces inside metadata. `,
      "metaData": [
        `

Comment: I copy your text from the question in VSCode and I can match the text with the `,(\n)\s*"metaData":[\s\S\n]*?\n\s*}\s*\n` pattern. Replace with `$1`. Please make sure you paste the exact text you work with.

Comment: write a simple python script to process the file

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am. I am trying with the same text i pasted above. Doesn't seem to work for me. I must be copying the pattern wrong. Thanks anyways.

Comment: My VSCode version is 1.31.0, `Version: 1.31.0 (user setup)
Commit: 7c66f58312b48ed8ca4e387ebd9ffe9605332caa
Date: 2019-02-05T22:35:56.624Z
Electron: 3.1.2
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601`

Comment: Mine is `Version: 1.41.1 (system setup)
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T14:58:56.166Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.16299`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in vscode:

`(^\s*"_.*"?\n)|(,\n^\s*"metaData":\s*\[[\s\S]+?\s+\])|(^\s{4,}\}$\n)|(^\s{2}(?![\{\}]))`

and replace with nothing.

For the full explanation see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NmmeU5/5).

There are 4 alternatives strung together:

`(^\s*"_.*"?\n)` get `"_index": "db",` for example, including trailing newline

`(,\n^\s*"metaData":\s*\[[\s\S]+?\s+\])` get the `"metaData": [...]` and the preceding `,` at the the end of the preceding entry so as to eliminate the trailing `,` on the last entry in every field.

`(^\s{4,}\}$\n)` get the `}` that was the closing brace from `"_source": {` that is no longer needed.

`(^\s{2}(?![\{\}]))` just to fix the indentation since `"_source": {...}` was removed - gets the first two spaces on all lines without a `{` or `}` following them.  [You may have to play with the `2` spaces removed depending on your indentation settings.]

You can eliminate this last alternative if you want to just format the document <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> instead - it should delete those spaces.  I noticed though that reformatting in this way will reformat your:

```
"keyword": ["sample1", "service"],
```

to

```
 "keyword": [
   "sample1",
   "service"
 ],
```

which you may care about or not.

[image: json regex demo]

---

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but I am not sure it will work on `VSCode`

I tried that solution on `Sublime Text Editor` and it's working fine.So I think it will also work on `VSCode`.

Steps to Solve your first Problem(line Starting with `"_`):

1. Open Your Json file in `Sublime Text Editor`
2. Press `ctrl+H` and then click on `.*` symbol to enable regex (Make sure `.*` is enable).
3. then type this regex `^.*"_.*\n` in `find` section and leave `Replace` section empty and press `Replace` (do not write any thing in `Replace` Section)

Steps to Solve your first Problem(entire block of `metaData`):

1. Open Your Json file in `Sublime Text Editor`
2. Press `ctrl+H` and then click on `.*` symbol to enable regex (Make sure `.*` is enable).
3. then type this regex `\"metadata[^}]*\]` in `find` section and leave `Replace` section empty and press `Replace` (do not write anything in `Replace` Section)

do not forget to enable `.*` symbol(See below image)

[image]